# How to Delete a Column Programmatically?

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

How does one delete a column (or multiple columns) in Excel?

eg. How to delete column C and shift the rest left?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you find how to do it:

http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/258110-how-do-you-delete-excel-column

http://quicktestprofessional.wordpress.com/2008/02/14/delete-columns-from-xl-sheet/

Comment: One link is bad...could you instead distill and provide the answer with a reference to a link?

Answer (score 22):

Here is the solution to make it clearer (thanks to [Leniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/114029) for the link)

```
Excel.Range range = (Excel.Range)sheet.get_Range("C1", Missing.Value);
range.EntireColumn.Delete(Missing.Value);
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(range);
```

Comment: what is `sheet`... how are you getting it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41170869/how-to-delete-entire-row-if-a-match-is-made-in-a-cell-in-that-row

Comment: Thanks it save my time.

Answer (score 6):

This was the first result I hit and deleting a column in Excel doesn't need as much code as the current answers suggest. In fact (assuming you have a `Worksheet` object already, listed below as `mySheet`) all that is needed for the original question is:

```
mySheet.Columns["C"].Delete();
```

If you want to delete multiple columns then:

```
mySheet.Columns["C:D"].Delete();
```

You can specify a variable in the `Delete` method (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xldeleteshiftdirection?view=excel-pia) i.e.  `mySheet.Columns["C"].Delete(xlShiftToLeft)`but there's no need as the `Delete` method is smart enough to realise that the `Range` you are selecting is a single column, so will do this automatically.

You can also uses a numeric value to designate the column i.e. `mySheet.Columns[2].Delete()`

Comment: but mysheet.Columns("C").Delete(); make the application unresponsive if there are large number of rows under that column.